# Content type not available

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a custom content type of type Item(0*01) and created list definition with this content type. Feature is successfully activated and the list definition is default content type is my custom content type and everything is fine. The problem is the contenttype is not showing under the Site Settings-> galleries-> Site Content Type. this seems wired to me or am i doing something wrong ?.

Content Type (Elements.xml):

```
<ContentType ID="0x01004856d4dff1c145c39f2cf2b8ff55a4e7" Name="Risiko_mgmt_ContentType" Group="Custom Content Type" Description="Risiko Management Content Type" Inherits="FALSE" Version="0"> 
    <FieldRefs> 
       <FieldRef ID="{59FC4B64-0956-4901-BFCC-37E8960A36E3}" Name="EmployeeName"/> 
       <FieldRef ID="{E39476E4-7CC9-48B4-A856-105C10050DF9}" Name="Personroll"/>
    </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```

Comment: How you created the content type?

Comment: <ContentType ID="0x01004856d4dff1c145c39f2cf2b8ff55a4e7"
               Name="Risiko_mgmt_ContentType"
               Group="Custom Content Type"
               Description="Risiko Management Content Type"
               Inherits="FALSE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{59FC4B64-0956-4901-BFCC-37E8960A36E3}" Name="EmployeeName"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{E39476E4-7CC9-48B4-A856-105C10050DF9}" Name="Personroll"/></FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>

Comment: What is the feature scope?

Comment: It is site Scoped